# Traffic distribution inside an GCP instance group

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, load-balancing, google-cloud-load-balancer, gce-instance-group

I have a *regional instance group* with 2 instances serving on port 8000, no autoscaling enabled.

This instance group is the backend of a *Global external application load balancer*.

The web server on the instances is running flask and each request will take 1 second to process:

```py
@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def main() -> Response:
    sleep(1)
    response = jsonify(
        success=True,
        hostname=gethostname(),
    )
    response.status_code = 200
    response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
    return response
```

I can confirm the behaviour by hitting the global load balancer public ip, ie takes 1 sec to get a response.

If I run 2 request at the same time, as there are 2 instances, I am expecting that each request will go to a different instance instead they always go to the same instance and they are queued on it, so:

- one request will take 1 sec
- the other request will take 2 sec

I have tried to change the `Locality load balancing policy` to `Round-Robin`, `Least-Request` and `Random`, but I always get the same behaviour.

Am I understanding correctly that `Locality load balancing policy` is only about which backend will be chosen? If yes how do you configure the load balancing policy inside a backend (ie instance group)?

Thanks

## Configuration

### Instance group

- Regional
- Target distribution shape: Even
- [x] Allow instance redistribution
- Autoscaling on: min 2, max 2
- Autoscaling signal: HTTP load-balancing 100%
- Initialisation period: 60s
- Health check:

  - Path: /health
  - Protocol: HTTP
  - Port: 8000
  - Interval: 30 sec
  - Timeout: 30 sec
  - Healthy threshold: 1
  - Unhealthy threshold: 10

### Load balancer

- Frontend:

  - Protocol: HTTP
  - IP: x.x.x.x
  - Network Tier: Premium
  - HTTP keepalive timeout: 610 sec
- Routing rules: All unmatched
- Backend services:

  - Endpoint protocol: HTTP
  - Named port: web
  - Timeout: 300 seconds
  - Cloud CDN: Disabled
  - Logging: Enabled (sample rate: 1)
  - Session affinity: None
  - Connection draining timeout: 300 seconds
  - Traffic policy:

    - Locality load balancing policy: Round robin
    - Outlier detection: Disabled
  - Backend security policy: None
  - Edge security policy: None
  - Identity-Aware Proxy: Disabled
- Balancing mode: Max. RPS: 1 (per instance)
- Capacity: 100%

## Test

```bash
siege \
    --concurrent 1 \
    --time 60s \
    "http://x.x.x.x"
```

With 2 nodes:

- `concurrent=1`: avg 1.02 sec
- `concurrent=2`: avg 1.66 sec
- `concurrent=4`: avg 3.35 sec
- `concurrent=8`: avg 5.54 sec

With 4 nodes:

- `concurrent=1`: avg 1.02 sec
- `concurrent=2`: avg 1.18 sec
- `concurrent=4`: avg 2.70 sec
- `concurrent=8`: avg 3.83 sec
- `concurrent=16`: avg 7.26 sec

With 8 nodes:

- `concurrent=2`: avg 1.20 sec
- `concurrent=4`: avg 1.85 sec
- `concurrent=16`: avg 4.40 sec
- `concurrent=64`: avg 14.06 sec
- `concurrent=128`: avg 19.04 sec

## Expected behaviour

I would have assumed results like:

- 2 nodes:

  - `concurrent=1`: 1 sec
  - `concurrent=2`: 1 sec
  - `concurrent=4`: ~2 sec
  - `concurrent=8`: ~4 sec
- 4 nodes:

  - `concurrent=1`: 1 sec
  - `concurrent=2`: 1 sec
  - `concurrent=4`: 1 sec
  - `concurrent=8`: ~2 sec
  - `concurrent=16`: ~4 sec

## Update 1

If I switch to a `Classic proxy network load balancer` and I send 100 requests:

- 56 go to vm0
- 44 go to vm1

Instead for an HTTP LB:

- 99 go to vm0
- 1 go to vm1

Comment: Have you checked if you have session affinity enabled on your load balancer?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using the default (None) and checked in the console `Session affinity: None`

Comment: @mrexojo could you check my update? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It might be the configuration in the load balancing policy Max. RPS: 1 (per instance) setting is causing requests to queue on a single instance instead of distributing them evenly. You can try to change the configuration of the load balancer of `Balancing mode` to `Rate`.

You can check if you can modify your Flask application to handle multiple requests concurrently. You can use the `concurrent` parameter in the `siege` command.  As an example:

`siege --concurrent 2 "`[`http://x.x.x.x`](http://x.x.x.x)`"`

This will send 2 requests concurrently . This may be a workaround to simulate the concurrent requests and does not change the actual behavior of the Flask application.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I am replicating a case where the server can only handle 1 request at the time.
The `Balancing mode` is already set to `rate`.
Anyway I get the same behavior:
* 0.5 sec request and rate 1 rps
* 2 sec request and rate 1 rps